# Setting Lightswitch Email Address Editor width

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch 2011 application with an Email address inpput.

For some reason, I cannot set the width on it - it ignores it unless I set it to Stretch (but then the control is centered which is not what I want).

When the user types in the text box it then expands. The same behaviour happens with the Currency Editor control.

How do I set the width on this control? I have included a video to demonstrate the problem.

[Video of width setting issues](http://screencast.com/t/DG6jHmcJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yann pointed out - it is a known bug in LS 2011 and **works fine after I upgraded to LS 12** in Visual Studio 2012 (i.e. as expected)

Answer (score 1):

You need to select anything other than *Stretch* (in your case, shown in the video, I'd suggest *Left*), then select the *Pixels* option, entering the *width* that you want.

You may have tried this combination, but unless you do it in the correct sequence, it sometimes ignores your selections. This is a known bug in LS 2011. I hope it's fixed in V2, but I haven't started using V2 yet, so I can't confirm that it has been fixed.

The order that I use to get around this is as follows:

1. Select Left
2. Select Pixels
3. Type in the width
4. Click on another textbox before you save

Edit: removed "or move on to the next control" from step 4

Comment: Thanks Yann, but unfortunately this still does not work for me - I have them all Left as default. I tried setting them to another value, e.g. Stretch, and then coming back in and following your sequence but no joy. I am installing VS12 today so will see if it is fixed

Comment: It really can literally depend on the exact order of the steps, which is silly, because it shouldn't. Reading my earlier reply, "or move to the next control" may not be correct. I actually never do that, so I don't even know why I wrote that. I *always* click on another property after setting the pixels property. So, if you were following that, you might try clicking on a property instead of moving to the next control. I learned the hard way, that was how to do it.

Comment: No problem - I have given up on 2011 and am only working in 2012 -there's some great improvements, including this bug fix. The new skin looks pretty awesome too.